# Execution failed for task '_app_transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

Everytime I try to run my android app, the following error emerges...

> Execution failed for task '_app_transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'
>    More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/macosx-x86_64/libusb-1.0.dylib'

My app's build.gradle file looks like this...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yusaf.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // openCV library
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary')
    // Bytedeco library
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3.3'
}
```

Does anyone know of any solutions? I tried to find the files but I've gotten nowhere so far...